# How to fix my screen? Black line and flashes when unplugged

Tags: display, laptop-display

My screen just did this thing:

[image: photo of the problematic screen]

How to fix this? Also my computer screen flashes when unplugged. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a hardware defect or a badly connected cable. Is this a laptop monitor? If not unplug everything. Replug and reboot. Also does it still do this if you boot with a live system. If yes the thing is starting to die on you.